# Can't install Django on Windows in a virtualenv

Tags: python, django

I have used PIP install Django in my virtualenv and I get the following message:
    Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in virtual\env\folder\lib\site-packages\django-1.7.6-py2.7.egg

However in the tutorial it is expecting a django-admin.py file in the lib folder. Previously lib==scripts when using Windows but the file is in neither lib nor scripts.

What do I need to do in order to have my django-admin file in the correct directory?

Scripts directory:

```
 Directory of          C:\virtual\env\folder\Scripts

18/03/2015  10:23    <DIR>          .
18/03/2015  10:23    <DIR>          ..
18/03/2015  10:23             2,379 activate
18/03/2015  10:23               596 activate.bat
18/03/2015  10:23             8,252 activate.ps1
18/03/2015  10:23             1,129 activate_this.py
18/03/2015  10:23               348 deactivate.bat
18/03/2015  10:22            95,138 easy_install-2.7.exe
18/03/2015  10:22            95,138 easy_install.exe
18/03/2015  10:23            95,110 pip.exe
18/03/2015  10:23            95,110 pip2.7.exe
18/03/2015  10:23            95,110 pip2.exe
18/03/2015  10:22            26,624 python.exe
18/03/2015  10:22            27,648 pythonw.exe
          12 File(s)        542,582 bytes
           2 Dir(s)  54,728,036,352 bytes free
```

thanks

Comment: Sorry, I guess I did not properly answer your last question. Are you using regular `cmd` or PowerShell? Can you try `Get-Command *virtualenv*` in a powershell?

Comment: I didn't ask the right question!

Comment: I don't seem to be able to enter the output though of that command

Comment: bit of progress - i have found the django-admin file all the way down here;

    \virtual_env\lib\site-packages\django-1.7.6-py2.7.egg\django\bin>

is there any reason why it needs to be all the way down there? Can i move it up

Comment: What does your PowerShell prompt look like? When you're working in the virtualenv (usually done with `workon MyProject`), then your path should be set up to execute the commands without moving anything around. I don't have any experience with virtualenv on Windows, but let's see if we can get this figured out.

Comment: (gesplosh) PS C:\Users\nicka_000\Documents\Coding\websites_go_here\gesplosh>

Comment: (gesplosh) PS C:\Users\nicka_000\Documents\Coding\websites_go_here\gesplosh> workon gesplosh
workon : The 'workon' command was found in the module 'VirtualEnvWrapper', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module VirtualEnvWrapper'.
At line:1 char:1
+ workon gesplosh
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (workon:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule

Comment: so i thought i would start from scratch - I deactivated the virtual env, deleted the folder "gesplosh", then recreated the virtual env and installed django again

I was told Django had installed successfully and the django-admin file is in the scripts folder

I then ran 

    .\scripts\django-admin.py startproject gesplosh

which opened up django-admin.py in notepad and didn't create anything... this feels like I am on the right track but still no cigar!

Comment: sorry for lack of formatting - for some reason I can't format on this question... no doubt doing something wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried virtualenvwrapper? It makes life as a developer much, much easier.

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

Then an example on getting started:

```
mkvirtualenv myproject # only necessary the first time
workon myproject # for an existing virtualenv
pip install django
django-admin.py startproject myproject
...
deactivate virtualenvwrapper
```

virtualenvwrapper has taken care of a lot of the pathing issues I've run into on Windows (I have a VM which has to support specific versions of Windows, Mac, and Vagrant). I hope this helps.

Regards,

-Tim